# Image missing in RSS/ATOM with Django

Tags: python, django, rss, atom-feed, django-1.11

I'm trying to attach an image to my ATOM and RSS syndication feed thanks to the Django's documentation : https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/ref/contrib/syndication/

I have to kind of feed : http://example.com/rss and http://mywebsite.com/atom

**rss.py**

```
class LatestEntriesFeed(Feed):
title = "MyWebsite"
link = "/"
description = "Latest news"


def items(self):
    return Articles.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-date')[:5]

def item_description(self, item):
    return '<![CDATA[ <img src="http://example.com/image.jpeg" /> ]]>'

def item_title(self, item):
    return item.title

def item_pubdate(self, item):
    return item.date

def item_updateddate(self, item):
    return item.update

def item_author_name(self, item):
    return item.author

def item_author_link(self, item):
    item_author_link = Site_URL + reverse('team', kwargs={'username': item.author})
    return item_author_link

def item_author_email(self):
    return EMAIL_HOST_USER

class LatestEntriesFeedAtom(LatestEntriesFeed):
    feed_type = Atom1Feed
    subtitle = LatestEntriesFeed.description
```

So I think I have to use CDATA into the description html tag. However, in Django (version 1.11), item_description doesn't return `<description>` tag in the XML, but a `<summary>` tag.

Is it fine or is it the source of the issue ?

Otherwise, I tried to scan with W3C validator and I get 2 errors (or just warnings ?)

1) Self reference doesn't match document location

2) Invalid HTML: Expected '--' or 'DOCTYPE'. Not found. (5 occurrences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
I gave up the CDATA tag to follow this kind of structure :

```
def item_description(self, item):
  return '<figure><img src="http://example.com/image.jpeg" class="type:primaryImage" /><figcaption><p>My Image description</p></figcaption></figure><p>Some text</p>'
```

I was helped by the Google manual : https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/9545420?hl=fr